# Global Rails admin app: load database settings dynamic at runtime to hook into several apps and adminster tasks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, admin, administration

I'm looking to build a centralized admin to manage tasks for several Ruby on Rails apps, 
therefore I have build the basic layout with autenthication which I want to connect to several Ruby on Rails apps "on the fly".

The idea is you login to the admin app, select the rubyapp you want to administer and it would connect to the appropriate database and gives some options to edit,delete,view, change records just like a regular scaffold.

Are there general concepts or best practice ways of doing this?
I have looked into external databases in rails already but for the rest I'm rather clueless on the approach to build this since there seems not much info available on this topic.

Who can help me to get on the right track? thx

Comment: The basic idea is very simple just "hookinto"an existing database from this rails superadmin app and do general stuff like get data in and out of the external database of each app you "hook into" I havent found any real examples on how to approach this so far.

Comment: development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: <name of your database>
  username: <user name to log on to your postgres db say:  postgres >
  password: <password>
  host: <give the IP address of your remote database.  eg. 192.168.1.1 >

Answer (score 2):

The obvious solution is to make each new sub-app as a part of the primary app which manages user administration and acces, with all users signing up once and applying for access to each "sub-app" function.

Comment: Im not quite sure how I should read your answer. You describe another approch here than My question looks for. What I read from this is We should need to be able to dynamically load a database configuration for one of the apps you want to adminster, then you can just code like regular? You would have several database.yml files and just load the correct one in? Not sure if this would be possible at runtime since the database.yml is parsed in the rails startup app start process If Im correct.

Comment: I think siggy is just saying make each app just a folder within one big application.

Comment: Yes make the apps part of a bigger app ( the admin ) but I don't want it that way. The apps are totally separated the admin apps should just hook into the db ( load external db true database.yml) is as far as I got on finding info on this.